# Set map center in leaflet with 3857 lat/lon

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to set map center with lat/lon of 3857 projection in leaflet. By using lat/lon of projection 4326 its working fine.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
    }).setView([51.40457186188496, -2.3741738081973844], 13);
```

But it dose not working if i provide 3857 lat/lon.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857
        }).setView([6693172.2381477, -264291.81938326], 13);
```

Please help me where I am wrong.

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Do you want to double check that ```crs``` property in the first code chunk? Does "not working" mean that the machine crashes, it goes to the wrong point, the call appears to have no effect, or something else? Remember we can't see your screen, so you have to describe it to us in some detail. If it goes to the wrong spot, try [5722330.76, -264367.49]

Comment: Thanks @BradHards
its means map not display. i think there is problem with bbox.when i use 3857 lat/lng. 

http://ms.piemapping.com/?map=/ms/mapfiles/wms-fg-900913.map&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=basemap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&HEIGHT=256&WIDTH=256&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=-5635549.2214094745,19411336.207077075,-5009377.085697311,20037508.34278071

Comment: I think you need to update your question (just click edit below the question) with more details. Such as the CRS of the map, source of data, the exact error, etc